# vba macro for counting emails from yesterday

Tags: vba

I am looking for a vba macro to count the number of emails in an inbox receivedtime of yesterday.

*SentAt time tends to throw off my numbers with emails sent close to midnight*.

Once I have this count, I need to add it to the sum of emails for another 20 or so mailboxes with same setup.

The current script will populate all emails in the mailbox (regardless of date), then will show how many in that folder by date so it's not really what I need.

```
Sub HowManyEmails()

Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim EmailCount As Integer
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    On Error Resume Next
    Set objFolder = objnSpace.Folders("Mailbox - IT Support Center").Folders("Onshore - Jim").Folders("completed1")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    MsgBox "No such folder."
    Exit Sub
    End If

EmailCount = objFolder.Items.Count

MsgBox "Number of emails in the folder: " & EmailCount, , "email count"

Dim dateStr As String
Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
Dim dict As Object
Dim msg As String
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set myItems = objFolder.Items
myItems.SetColumns ("ReceivedTime")
' Determine date of each message:
For Each myItem In myItems
    dateStr = GetDate(myItem.ReceivedTime)
    If Not dict.Exists(dateStr) Then
        dict(dateStr) = 0
    End If
    dict(dateStr) = CLng(dict(dateStr)) + 1
Next myItem

' Output counts per day:
msg = ""
For Each o In dict.Keys
    msg = msg & o & ": " & dict(o) & " items" & vbCrLf
Next
MsgBox msg

Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objnSpace = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What's in `GetDate` ?  Maybe you can compare `GetDate(myItem.ReceivedTime)` with `GetDate(Date()-1)` to determine if a mail was received yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to simplify your code:

```
Sub HowManyEmails()

Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim MailItem
Dim EmailCount As Integer

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

On Error Resume Next
Set objFolder = objnSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Onshore - Jim").Folders("completed1")
On Error GoTo 0

If objFolder Is Nothing Then MsgBox "No Such Folder": Exit Sub

For Each MailItem In objFolder.Items
    If DatePart("d", Date - 1) = DatePart("d", MailItem.ReceivedTime) Then EmailCount = EmailCount + 1
Next

MsgBox EmailCount
Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objnSpace = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing

End Sub
```

This counts all mails that was received yesterday stored in the specified folder.
I added the `.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)` assuming that your subfolders are inside `Inbox`.
This way, outlook knows exactly where to search.

However, what if you are not accessing the Inbox folder but another folder in your mailbox?
Above code will not work and you will need something like this:

```
Sub HowManyMails()

Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder, objNotInbox As MAPIFolder
Dim MailItem
Dim EmailCount As Integer
Dim strFolderName

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objnSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) 'reference to default folder

strFolderName = objFolder.Parent 'referrence to Inbox's parent which is Mailbox

On Error Resume Next
Set objNotInbox = objnSpace.Folders(strFolderName).Folders("Onshore - Jim").Folders("completed1")
On Error GoTo 0

If objNotInbox Is Nothing Then MsgBox "No Such Folder": Exit Sub

For Each MailItem In objNotInbox.Items
    If DatePart("d", Date - 1) = DatePart("d", MailItem.ReceivedTime) Then EmailCount = EmailCount + 1
Next

MsgBox EmailCount
Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objnSpace = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing

End Sub
```

The above will count the number of mails in a folder within your `Mailbox`("Mailbox - IT Support Center") which is of the same level as `Inbox`(which is "OnShore -Jim" folder).
I removed the hard coded Mailbox name to make it more dynamic and just reference it to `Inbox` parent folder which is `Mailbox`.
Hope this get's you started to get what you want.

**Additional:**(loop all folders in Mailbox)

```
Sub HowManyMails()

Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder, objNotInbox As MAPIFolder
Dim MailItem
Dim EmailCount As Integer
Dim strFolderName
Dim FolderName() As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objnSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

strFolderName = objFolder.Parent

ReDim FolderName(3) 'change this to how many folders you have

'assign each folder name on the array elements
FolderName(1) = "OnShore - Jim" 
FolderName(2) = "OnShore - John"
FolderName(3) = "OnShore - Ben"

'loop through each foldername
For i = 1 To 3
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objNotInbox = objnSpace.Folders(strFolderName).Folders(FolderName(i)).Folders("completed1")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If objNotInbox Is Nothing Then GoTo skip

    For Each MailItem In objNotInbox.Items
        If DatePart("d", Date - 1) = DatePart("d", MailItem.ReceivedTime) Then EmailCount = EmailCount + 1
    Next
skip:
Next

MsgBox EmailCount

End Sub
```

In the above code, i assumed your folders are not inside `Inbox`.
If the folders are inside `Inbox`, modify the first code instead.

Comment: Ultimately, what I want to do is add up all "completed" mailbox counts from previous day. The path to the completed mailboxes is all the same except the person's name is different. Please help

Comment: you just need to add an array containing the names of the folders. then create another loop to iterate each and every folder. See my updated post.

Comment: The actual path to the folder is .Folders("Mailbox - IT Support Center").Folders("OnShore - Jim").Folders("completed1"). So the only thing that changes is the name on each one. FolderName(1) = "OnShore - Jim" might need to be tweeked and also Set objNotInbox = objnSpace.Folders(strFolderName).Folders(FolderName(i)).Folders("completed1")   Let me know and Thank you for the array, it works, just need the folder path and I'm not sure having the parent folder.

Comment: yep correct. i'm not certain on the folder path and only second guessing. i just showed you how to do it and leave the rest of the editting to you. :)